# Counting length-2 substrings that are common to two strings at the same offset -- Python

Tags: python, beginner, strings, programming-challenge, unit-testing

I solved the CodingBat task:

> Given 2 strings, a and b, return the number of the positions where they contain the same length 2 substring. So "xxcaazz" and "xxbaaz"
> yields 3, since the "xx", "aa", and "az" substrings appear in the same
> place in both strings.
>
> ```
> stringMatch("xxcaazz", "xxbaaz") → 3  
> stringMatch("abc", "abc") → 2  
> stringMatch("abc", "axc") → 0
> ```

```
import doctest


def all_two_chars_occurencies(string):
    """
    >>> list(all_two_chars_occurencies('abcd'))
    ['ab', 'bc', 'cd']
    >>> list(all_two_chars_occurencies('xxcaazz'))
    ['xx', 'xc', 'ca', 'aa', 'az', 'zz']
    """
    for index, char in enumerate(string[:-1]):
        yield char + string[index + 1]


def common_two_chars_occurences(a, b):
    """
    Given 2 strings, a and b, return the number of the positions where
    they contain the same length 2 substring.

    >>> common_two_chars_occurences('xxcaazz', 'xxbaaz')
    3
    >>> common_two_chars_occurences('abc', 'abc')
    2
    >>> common_two_chars_occurences('abc', 'axc')
    0
    """
    equal_duets = 0
    for a_duet, b_duet in zip(all_two_chars_occurencies(a),
                              all_two_chars_occurencies(b)):
        if a_duet == b_duet:
            equal_duets += 1
    return equal_duets


if __name__ == "__main__":
    doctest.testmod()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such word as "occurencies".  In any case, `all_two_chars_occurencies` is a very long name.  I suggest `pairwise_chars`.  Note that it could also be written in a style similar to the [`pairwise()` recipe in Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

In Python, explicit looping is slightly cumbersome.  Fortunately, Python offers many ways to just do what you want as a "one-liner", without looping.  Here's one approach, which uses a generator expression, and [this technique](//stackoverflow.com/a/7223557/1157100) to find its length.

```
def common_two_chars_occurences(a, b):
    """
    Given 2 strings, a and b, return the number of the positions where
    they contain the same length 2 substring.

    >>> common_two_chars_occurences('xxcaazz', 'xxbaaz')
    3
    >>> common_two_chars_occurences('abc', 'abc')
    2
    >>> common_two_chars_occurences('abc', 'axc')
    0
    """
    return sum(1 for pair
                 in zip(pairwise_chars(a), pairwise_chars(b))
                 if pair[0] == pair[1])
```

Comment: Note that you can sum booleans and use unpacking to get `sum(left == right for left, right in zip(pairwise_chars(a), pairwise_chars(b)))`. My preference is actually `sum(map(eq, pairwise_chars(a), pairwise_chars(b)))` though (`eq` from `operator`).

Answer (score 1):

You should refactor further writing an `equal_at_same_index` function:

```
def equal_at_same_index(list_1, list_2):
    """
    >>> equal_at_same_index("abcde", "xxcae")
    2
    >>> equal_at_same_index("qwerty", "xqwerty")
    0
    """
    return sum((i == j for i, j in zip(list_1, list_2)))


def common_two_chars_occurences(a, b):
    """
    Given 2 strings, a and b, return the number of the positions where
    they contain the same length 2 substring.

    >>> common_two_chars_occurences("xxcaazz", "xxbaaz")
    3
    >>> common_two_chars_occurences("abc", "abc")
    2
    >>> common_two_chars_occurences("abc", "axc")
    0
    """
    return equal_at_same_index(all_two_chars_occurencies(a),
                               all_two_chars_occurencies(b))
```